# Attempting to update pacman fails due to dependencies. What am I Missing?

Tags: dependencies, pacman

- removing libpamac breaks dependency 'libpamac>=11.4' required by arcolinux-pamac-all
- removing libpamac breaks dependency 'libpamac' required by libpamac-flatpak-plugin
- removing libpamac breaks dependency 'libpamac>=11.5.0' required by pamac-gtk

I am running ArcoLinux